# How to create a timed shutdown, based on idle state?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, idle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I shutdown my PC when the system is idle?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215870/how-can-i-shutdown-my-pc-when-the-system-is-idle)

In Ubuntu 11.10, when I go to System Settings > Power, I get the option to suspend my machine after it's been idle for a set period.

How can I set the machine to shut down instead?

To be clear, I am not interested in setting the machine to simply shutdown after a specific amount of time or at a specified time, as is possible with the `shutdown` command in terminal. I am interested in my machine automically shuting down and powering off a set period of time after I last did anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible in the power settings, you can however install an application called EasyShutdown that will let you achieve what you want.

To find out more visit the [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown) for the project.

Comment: EasyShutdown does not allow one to time the shutdown after time the machine has been idle. ComplexShutdown linked to from that site does, though!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gnome 3 you can install an extension called **Shutdown Timer** , you can find it in this link:
[Shutdown Timer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/183/shutdown-timer/)