# How can I shutdown my PC when the system is idle?

Tags: shutdown

I am using Ubutnu 12.04 LTS. Now I am here to know that, is there any script/application I can use to shutdown my Ubuntu when my system is IDLE for 10 Minutes or so?

I have already gone through [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110982/how-to-create-a-timed-shutdown-based-on-idle-state), but it doesn't seems to be help me much and that package also not active from long time.

Any script/Application I can get for this?

Thank you all.

Comment: I made a little program that switches off the light at my desk when the screensaver turns on. It should be pretty easy to adapt for shutting down the machine. Is that what you are looking for? Otherwise you should define what 'idle' means in this context.

Comment: Even some download or updating going means after sometime screensaver will active . so I can't call this state as idle .

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ yes I can .

Comment: I dont have any techical info but i have idea . if we change sleeping sccript to shutdown scpript it can work

Comment: ComplexShutdown has disabled option of setting idle time. This is reported as a bug. :( Idon't know , if it is on every system like that... I used lxle 12.04 distro

Answer (score 2):

Edit: you can do this with https://launchpad.net/complexshutdown

If you're interested in *how* this works, look at [How does ubuntu determine inactivity before suspending?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170307/how-does-ubuntu-determine-inactivity-before-suspending) for a good start.  You can access the same counters that Ubuntu already uses before suspending, when suspend-on-idle is on.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

1. You could use a download manager application, they usually have an auto shutdown option. Search for one, where you can configure the idle time.
2. use a cron script: [How can I shutdown the computer when a certain process ends?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174169/how-can-i-shutdown-the-computer-when-a-certain-process-ends?rq=1)
3. configure your PC to go to sleep (hibernate) when there is no activity for a while
4. read the "related" box, right on your screen, and pick up one appropriate tip